# Google Data Studio copy text from table (to clipboard)

Tags: android, clipboard, looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio dashboard that allows users to search a list of people by various criteria. They need to find the person they're looking for in a table and copy-and-paste one of the fields of interest into another application.

On desktop, it's possible to highlight and copy as normal, but on Android (phone and tablet) I can't figure out how to do it:

- Long-pressing text brings up the Data Studio context menu. The text also becomes highlighted, but no clipboard menu appears (see image).
- Double-tapping triggers the browser's auto-zoom instead of highlighting
- Tapping and dragging does nothing

**To replicate:**

- Open this [Example table](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/7311c6b5-d77a-414d-ad66-a19d3a4ba50b) on an Android device in Chrome or Firefox
- Attempt to highlight text from the table and copy it to the clipboard

**Desired behavior:**

- Text can be highlighted and copied

**Current behavior:**

- The browser either zooms, or opens the Data Studio context menu, but it is not possible to highlight and copy text.

At this point I'm open to any kind of workaround, even if it's onerous or messy.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Use cross-filtering to feed the selected row's ID into a scorecard or other element: Scorecards have the same behavior
- Turn off cross-filtering: This removes the interactivity where tapping a row highlights it, but doesn't change the behavior described above.
- Try different mobile browser. I can make it work in Firefox Nightly, which allows you to disable double-tap-to-zoom and in Puffin Browser, which doesn't implement it in the first place. However, neither of these is a good solution for users.
- Use presentation mode: If I put the data sheet in presentation mode, turn the device to landscape, and set it to full-width then I can usually but not consistently copy text in Firefox, but not in chrome.

[image: Data Studio sort menu instead of clipboard menu]